# Outlook: better way to organize sent mails into specific folders?

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2007

I heavily rely on organizing all my emails into folders (my brain finds email faster when they're grouped to a certain "topic"). I'm not only putting my received mails into them but also my sent ones, so all emails from a thread are together.

Every time I send an email from a thread, I've to manually move the email to the specific folder (it may be a public folder, but usually isn't).

Is there a way to optimize this?

1. Can this be done automatically? I imagine I could do it by setting up hundreds of rules (I've literally hundreds of folders ...)
2. I always have to do it manually after I send the email. This is error prone/annoying (actually less error prone in my case, but annoys me); would it be possible to choose "do not put it into Sent but into this folder" ?

I guess what I would like to see is some kind of automation. If I reply to/forward an email from a folder (except "Inbox"), let Outlook put this just sent email into this folder instead of "Sent".

I'm using Outlook 2007.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The option is hidden away:

`Tools` -> `Options` -> `E-mail Options...` -> `Advanced E-mail Options...` -> `In folders other than the Inbox, save replies with original message`

[image]

Update for later version of Outlook - the option has moved and been renamed:

`File` -> `Options` -> `Mail` -> `Save Messages` -> `When replying to a message that is not in the Inbox, save the reply in the same folder`

[image]

(Screenshot from Outlook 2010)

Comment: Important to remember that the original has to be in the other folder before you click the reply button or that setting doesn't take effect.

Comment: Jesus! I actually didn't believe this would be possible, but works absolutely fantastic, thank you so much!